# Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis Heroku (RedisToGo)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, redis, sidekiq

This question may the duplication of other question, I tried every possible solution on the existing discussion but none of them are working.

I'm trying to use Redis on the Heroku using the RedisToGo.
Here is my output of the `heroku config`

```
REDISTOGO_URL:                redis://redistogo:....@albacore.redistogo.com:11539/
REDIS_PROVIDER:               REDISTOGO_URL
REDIS_URL:                    redis://....@albacore.redistogo.com:11539/
```

When I run the command `heroku run bundle exec sidekiq` I'm getting following error,

```
4 TID-81oc0 INFO: Booting Sidekiq 4.1.2 with redis options {:size=>2, :url=>"redis://redistogo:REDACTED@albacore.redistogo.com:11539/"}
Error connecting to Redis on albacore.redistogo.com:11539 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:345:in `rescue in establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:331:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:101:in `block in connect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:293:in `with_reconnect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:100:in `connect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:364:in `ensure_connected'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.3.0/lib/redis/client.rb:221:in `block in process'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
4 TID-lvm10 INFO: [Sidetiq] Sidetiq::Actor::Clock id: 36749520 shutting down ...
4 TID-lrfno INFO: [Sidetiq] Sidetiq::Actor::Handler id: 36587080 shutting down ...
4 TID-znma0 INFO: [Sidetiq] Sidetiq::Actor::Handler id: 59890980 shutting down ...
4 TID-lrbco INFO: [Sidetiq] Sidetiq::Actor::Handler id: 36548460 shutting down ...
4 TID-zm5yo INFO: [Sidetiq] Sidetiq::Actor::Handler id: 59822760 shutting down ...
4 TID-zmyrw INFO: [Sidetiq] Sidetiq::Actor::Handler id: 59884740 shutting down ...
4 TID-zog78 INFO: [Sidetiq] Sidetiq::Actor::Handler id: 59929360 shutting down ...
4 TID-zm9y0 INFO: [Sidetiq] Sidetiq::Actor::Handler id: 59853240 shutting down ...
4 TID-zlj9g INFO: [Sidetiq] Sidetiq::Actor::Handler id: 59793140 shutting down ...
```

I went through the every possible solution on the StackOverflow but still could not make it working. Any suggestion will be appreciated.